# How to open "home screen" from webos

Tags: javascript, html, webos, lg

I'm fresh in webos development, I'm trying to open **home screen** (picture attached at the end) once user press back on my application home page.
The issue is I'm not able to find an example for this by googling.
I have as an example how to increase volume up:

```
webOS.service.request("luna://com.webos.audio", {
            method: "volumeUp",
            onComplete: function (inResponse) {

            },
            onFailure: function (inError) {

            }
        });
```

I checked all [luna services](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/api/webos-service-api/) but didn't find a hint for triggering home screen.
Please help me in this.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

**update**: in case it's not possible to find out a straightforward way, is there any way to trigger keypress event to host system? where I will send smart key ID.

Comment: any idea or at least a direction to dig after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Reference, you can use this [link](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-developer-guide/back-button) to perform the required.
it has all the needed info.

---

1- downlaod webOs.js file from [here](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/download_file/view_inline/4144/)

---

2- include it in your application

---

3- you can use any of the explained methods in the link, for me I did the following:

---

- set disableBackHistoryAPI to true in appinfo.json `disableBackHistoryAPI: true;`
- on you home screen you can use the following call in your back function:

  webOS.platformBack();